# How to get firebug profiler to show functions as non-anonymous

Tags: javascript, firebug, prototype, profiler, anonymous

On a Mac, Firebug outputs proper function names in profiler mode. On a PC, allmost all functions are logged as 'anonymous'. In this instance, almost all the function calls are prototype methods. Is there a way to get at the function names on the PC version? A setting?

Here's the difference. You can see why the PC version is far inferior. This is profiling the exact same code! (Running FF 9, Latest stable Firebug)
[image]

Comment: Have you tried updating your Firefox & Firebug?  I remember seeing Firebug's release notes on a recent release related to this.

Comment: Fresh install yesterday (2012.01.23)of latest stable build.

Comment: I've notified the folks over at firebug. Strangely, anonymous functions like foo.prototype.bar = function(){} will resolve correctly to the prototype name on a mac, whereas on PC is resolves to anonymous.

Comment: On my Windows XP machine, surprisingly, IE8 seems to have the best support for displaying anonymous functions in profiler (dont't read it as 'IE has best profiler'; whole IE dev tools are painfully slow). They have some heuristics for doing it, as they described [in this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/11/introducing-the-ie8-developer-tools-jscript-profiler.aspx). In Firefox/Firebug, Chrome, Safari unnamed anonymous functions are displayed without the name unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, but I'd suggest posting to Firebug's user group: http://groups.google.com/group/firebug .  Good luck!

Comment: Here's the thread if you want to watch it: http://groups.google.com/group/firebug/browse_thread/thread/3607c112a826eb29/4e3ff33612e8ca7c?pli=1

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else works, you can always name the function:

```
var functionVariable = function nameVisibleToDebugger(parameters) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: If you were correct, it would be in global scope; since you are incorrect, it might be, and is, in function scope.

Comment: That's why I added "if I'm correct" - I was applying my expectation to Javascript, which - after 4 weeks of JS - turns out to be faulty...